# Noobie jquery class Q : internal function calls

Tags: jquery

I've got a breakpoint on line this.hide(); It gets found appropriately in firebug, but never passes through to the hide : function(). I assume that I'm making a really embarrassing noobie syntax error. Can someone please tell me the proper way to make this internal call?

Thanks!

```
var myDialog = myControl.extend( { 
    //init  

    show : function() {
        if (this.isModal) {
            this.overlay.unbind("click");
        } else {
            this.overlay.click(function(e) {
                this.hide();
            });
        }
    },

    hide : function() {
        this.overlay.hide();
        this.dialog.fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely not operating in the expected context in your this.overlay.click() handler.  Put a breakpoint on this.hide() and examine the "this" object.  I bet it is not what you were expecting!

You will want to cache "this" prior to that call such as:

```
show : function() {
    var context = this;
    if (this.isModal) {
        this.overlay.unbind("click");
    } else {
        this.overlay.click(function(e) {
            context.hide();
    });
},
```

Javascript context/scope is a tricky situation.

Comment: Wow! Great answer! Thank you so much... Just adding the locally-scoped context lines solved the problem, so I imagine that "this" was getting/trying to get changed during the this.hide() call, bumped into itself and abended. Wow, this question was not as dumb as I thought it was... Thanks for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because your `this.hide();` line is within a click event, `this` actually refers to the element that was clicked on.